# Flatten tuple containing list to multiple tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples that each contain a "key" and a list "value":

```
[('ABE', ['ORD', 'ATL', 'DTW'])]
```

Here, `ABE` is the "key" and the list `['ORD', 'ATL', 'DTW']` is the "value".

How can I "flatten" this RDD structure by mapping each of the original key-value tuples to three tuples, all with same "key" each with a different element of the value list?

My desired output is

```
[('ABE', 'ORD'), ('ABE','ATL'), ('ABE','DTW')]
```

Comment: Your first list is invalid. Also why the *spark tags?

Comment: @mozway Hi because i am using pySpark,

Comment: But you don't give any context to show how this is related

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in a single list comprehension:

```
data = [('ABE', ['ORD', 'ATL', 'DTW'])]

flattened = [
    (key, elem) 
    for key, value in data 
    for elem in value
]
print(flattened)
```

outputs

```
[('ABE', 'ORD'), ('ABE', 'ATL'), ('ABE', 'DTW')]
```

Comment: Thank you @Brian but I am getting the following error : 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable maube because the list iteself is an rdd ? This is how I created it data=links.map(lambda x :(x[0],list(set((list(x[1])))))) , X[0] is the airport and the second x[1] element is the different distinct destinations

Comment: Thank you I added collect() function to data and got the desired output. data = [('ABE', ['ORD', 'ATL', 'DTW'])]

flattened = [
    (key, elem) 
    for key, value in data.collect()
    for elem in value
]
print(flattened)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested Brian solution and got `"PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable"`.
Therefore I added `collect()` function for the data.

```
data = [('ABE', ['ORD', 'ATL', 'DTW'])]

flattened = [
    (key, elem)
    for key, value in data.collect()
    for elem in value
]

print(flattened)
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with key as `fillvalue`.

```
from itertools import zip_longest


lst = [('ABE', ['ORD', 'ATL', 'DTW']), ('1', ['A', 'B', 'C'])]


res = []
for key, sublist in lst:
    res.append(tuple(zip_longest([key], sublist, fillvalue=key)))

print(res)
```